# Division of Polynomial using Euclid's lemma

Tags: polynomials

Find the quotient and remainder  when $p(x)=x^3+4x^2-6x+2$ is divided by $g(x)=x-3$ without actually dividing or by long division method or by synthetic division methods.
I used Euclid's lemma $p(x)=g(x)q(x)+r(x)$ whre $q(x)$ is the quotient and $r(x)$ is the remainder.
$x^3+4x^2-6x+2$=$(x-3)(ax^2+bx+c)+(dx+k)$ where $ax^2+bx+c$ is the quotient and $dx+k$ is the remainder. I compared the coefficients on either sides but could not evaluate $d$

Comment: The remainder will be a constant, the value of $p(x)$ at $x=3$. In your notation, $d=0$. The remainder always has degree **less** than the degree of the thing we are dividing by.

Comment: I got it. But when $p(x)=4x^3+11x^2-11x+8$ is divided by $x^2-x+1$, the remainder is a constant. How are we going to decide the degree of the remainder depending upon the degrees of $p(x)$ and $g(x)$

Comment: @Achari No, by the Division Algorithm the remainder has smaller degree than the divisor, so for a quadratic divisor the remainder has degree $\le 1\,$ (so not necessarily constant).

Comment: @Achari Generally it is not possible to determine the degree of the remainder without computing it.